# FFMPEG create a demo file

Tags: php, ffmpeg

From a given file (eg test.mp4) I want to create a new file with exact same properties (eg video rate, resolution etc) with the only difference to be the duration. eg 10 minutes while the original can be 2 hours.

This will helps me to create preview video files.

PS1: This conversion should be done within a PHP file, so I'll appreciate the code to be in PHP.
PS2: For testing purposes the original file should be at /home/user/original and the new file must be at /home/user/demo

Thank you

Comment: Are you looking for help with code that you already wrote, or are you looking to hire someone to write the code for you?

Comment: The code was written by me. I mean the media script. But it came to my mind to create short demo videos so I can easily put them in public area (so easy to steal them), and keep the original videos outside the public area available only for download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Linux command to do it is:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:01 -i Demo.mp4 -to 00:05:00 -c copy NewDemo.mp4
```

To execute this command from within a PHP file, the syntax is:

```
shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -ss 00:00:01 -i /origin_folder/myvideo.mp4 -to 00:15:00 -c copy /destination_folder/mynewvideo.mp4 >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &');
```